# Safari declares link in new tab as popup after 1 second response time

Tags: ios, vue.js, safari, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt 3 application that runs in universal mode. One part of the app does the following: When clicking some button a server-side plugin function is called that sends a url to a tracking api and waits for the response, which would be a transformed url. After that the transformed url gets opened in a new tab.

So far, so simple.
Now I had the problem, that opening the url in a new tab sometimes gets blocked by safari on IOS and MacOs. It turned out that Safari somehow declares url's as popups, when a url should be opened in a new tab and the response takes too long.

It seems to happen, if the response lasts longer than 1000ms.

Does anyone have further information about this behaviour? I couldn't find any documentation about it and i would like to understand that behaviour better.

I would like to know the exact amount of time, when that happens. I also want to know if this behaviour could occur, when the device itself is slow and e.g. cannot handle the function fast enough. And I would like to know, if there is some best practice, so that I do not fall into that behaviour.